# In a sorted array of prime numbers arr find index i of the smallest number in arr such that arr[i] divides given number

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, primes

Consider the following data:
arr = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19]
n = 100
Output of the given should be 0 since n % 2 = 0 and arr[0] = 2.

Since array is sorted I want to use that to my advantage and design an algorithm that can work in a complexity smaller than O(n), which you have by iterating over the whole array and finding first i such that n % arr[i] = 0.

I instantly thought of using modified Binary Search with the same complexity as the regular Binary Search(O(logN)), which does the same as a regular Binary Search which divides the search interval in half in each iteration with slight modification. Here is the implementation i used:

```
public int SmallestFactorIndex(int n)
{
    int left = 0;
    int right = max;
    int index = -1;

    while (left <= right)
    {
        int middle = (right - left) / 2 + left;
        int middleValue = sieve[middle];

        if (n % middleValue == 0)
        {
            index = middle;
            right = middle - 1;
        }
        else if (middleValue < n)
        {
            left = middle + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            right = middle - 1;
        }
    }

    return index;
}
```

Max represents length of the array - 1 and sieve is the sorted array of prime numbers.
Only addition to the Binary Search is that if the current number does divide n, I dont instantly return that index but continue searching for a smaller number than that current number by moving the right border to the middle one. All other parts work pretty much the same way.
I dont think I can take advantage of the fact that the array only consists of the prime numbers but I might be wrong.

Comment: "an algorithm that can work in a complexity smaller than O(n)" why? If you need to manipulate the list into another format (such as a binary tree), that's going to be an O(n) operation, offsetting any advantage you get from another iteration method.

Comment: I think the fastest way is simply to iterate the list in ascending order until you find a divisor.

Comment: @harold Sorry you are right i overlooked that.

Comment: @gunr2171 I have several queries so i want to make this a log(N) operation

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes On one query it would be ok.

Comment: Yelling in the title is impolite

Comment: I want people to be aware

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i want to make this a log(N) operation

O(log n) is commonly associated with a binary algorithm: you split the data set at some midpoint; based on this midpoint you then decide which half to keep and which to discard, and repeat with the kept half until you zero in on the result.

This works *great* when the data is presorted (it is, yay) *and* an item can be known (on it's own!) to definitely solve the query. And there's our trouble. If `n` is, say, 286 (2 x 11 x 13), then any of 2, 11, and 13 are *potential* solutions, and landing on any of them via binary search doesn't tell us we're done until we fully complete the search... we still have to check everything.

Abstracting to the general case, this suggests a simple binary search on the array is *not good enough by itself*, because simply finding **A** solution doesn't stop the search for **THE** solution.

But it *can work* if we know the result in advance. That is, if we can solve to find the smallest prime factor (regardless of index) in O(log n) time — if we know the value we're looking for is the 2, instead of the 11 or the 13 — we can then also search the array in O(log n) time, and O(log n) plus O(log n) is still O(log n).

---

If we look at the input, fully factoring a number is definitely **NOT** O(log n) -- famously so, to the point a number of important cryptographic algorithms rely on this being *much* worse.

But we don't need to fully factor the number. We only need the *first* (smallest) prime. This can obviously do a little better... but is it good enough? And unfortunately, I think the answer is still, "no".

Reading a quick refresher, I think it's likely we *can* beat linear time for the average/typical case, and even make it all the way to O(sqrt n) to find the first prime. O(sqrt n<sub>0</sub>) + O(log n<sub>1</sub>) is still O(sqrt n), but at least it's still better (on the surface) than O(n).

---

But this is where things get a little tricky. Now we also have to worry about keeping the "n" from the input variable separate from the "n" for the primes array. When we do that, we realize the "n" for the input variable involves is *every integer* up to that value, rather than just the (much smaller) length of the pre-computed primes array.

Therefore, for typical `n` inputs up to about a million or so (and that number is a complete guess, but you could write some code to validate and refine it), the linear search is likely the best you can do.

---

Speaking of writing code to pre-validate inputs, this brings up the next option:

### O(1)

If you can put some kind of reasonable boundary on the possible input data, it's not out of the question to fully pre-compute the results for every candidate integer and put those values into a O(1) dictionary. Even a million candidates would only take about 8 MB RAM, and suddenly now every input only requires a dictionary lookup.

Comment: So no matter the data structure I use i cant achieve anything less than O(N)? The problem is I have several queries so I made a sieve of Erathostenes so I specified that I have sorted array of prime numbers thinking these two factors could help someone come up with a solution.

Comment: @NikolaSavić The point at the end of my answer about the nature of the data is worth reinforcing, so I'll restate using its inverse: if the data is truly unknown or random and includes _large_ numbers, you MAY do better by pre-factoring your inputs to find the smallest prime factor. Otherwise, knowing you already have a pre-computed a prime array up to `SQRT(integer.MaxValue)`, you're probably better off just iterating the array... if the index (rather than the value) is indeed what you're after.

Comment: Technically, it's an open question: we don't know any algorithms which return a prime factor in a logarithm time (and we don't have a proof that such algorithm doesn't exist). There's a hope that the fast algorithm can be found: we are able to check if `n` is prime or not with logarithmic time (AKS primality test), may be the last step - a factor can be logarithmic as well.

Answer (score 1):

> design an algorithm that can work in a complexity smaller than O(n)

The good news is that if `n` is not prime, then linearly going through the list is already only an O(sqrt(n)) algorithm: the smallest factor of a composite number cannot be larger than its square root. For a plain old `int` that's not too bad (but there's no hope of factoring an RSA key that way).

For an `n` that *is* prime, you can cut the linear search short when you reach a number larger than the square root of `n` (so this is still O(sqrt(n)) so far) and now you actually *can* use binary search to find the index of `n` itself (which must be the lowest prime to divide `n` at this point, since we just proved that `n` is prime), if it is in the list.

Using the PNT, I think we could even argue that the time complexity of linearly going through that list of primes until we find the lowest prime factor is O(sqrt(n) / log(n)). The division by log(n) comes from the density of primes "thinning out" as `n` increases (so we can reach the square root of `n` asymptotically faster by iterating only over the primes, as we do here, compared to iterating over the integers).

Answer (score 1):

Well, if `p` divides `n` then `p` is *at most* `sqrt(n)`: in the worst case `n = p * p`. Let's check prime numbers up to `sqrt(n)`:

```
public int SmallestFactorIndex(int n) {
  int result = -1;

  for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; ++i) {
    int d = arr[i];
  
    (int q, int r) = Math.DivRem(n, d);

    if (r == 0)
       return i;
    if (q <= d)
       return -1;
  }

  return result; 
}
```

So far so good we have `O(sqrt(n))` time complexity which is better than `O(n)`. We can be better off with more elaborated algorithms e.g. [Pollard's rho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm) which has `O(sqrt(sqrt(n))) = O(n^1/4)` time complexity, but still no logarithms here. For logarithm time you can only check if `n` prime or not ([AKS test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test)), but not find a prime factor.

Comment: Be careful not to conflate the `n` from the input variable with the `n` of the pre-computed primes array. We can certainly get to O(sqrt n) for the former, but then the n is potentially every positive integer, where with the latter is only the length of the array.